# How can I run code If any one of if else statements is true?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

Which condition keyword will run If one of if else statement run and it will run?

example:

```
int num = MyMathLibrary.random(1, 10);

if (num == 3){
    // do something
} else if (num == 7){
    // do something
} else if (num == 2){
    // do something
} runiftrue {
    // this "runiftrue" will run if any of if/else if statement is true
    // it means, if num = 3, or num = 7, or num = 2 it will run, but if num = 1 it will not run
}
```

before I use this:

```
int num = MyMathLibrary.random(1, 10);

boolean LastRun = false;


if (num == 3){
    LastRun = true;
    // do something
} else if (num == 7){
    LastRun = true;
    // do something
} else if (num == 2){
    LastRun = true;
    // do something
} 
    if (LastRun) {
        // this line of code will run if any of if/else if statement is true
        // it means, if num = 3, or num = 7, or num = 2 it will run, but if num = 1 it will not run
    }
```

but this way to do that is really not clever, and takes a lots of time to add
a "boolean LastRun = true". Are there any more clever, easier and clearer way to do that?

Comment: maybe the one that has a sintax error

Comment: @washcloth you means"runiftrue"? That because I don't know which keyword in java have same function as what I ask

Comment: It sounds like you just want `boolean lastRun = num == 3 || num == 7 || num == 2;` Or if you don't use that anywhere else, just `if (num == 3 || num == 7 || num == 2) { ... }` and don't have a local variable for it at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Conditions aren't correct. If `num==10`, it will already be covered in `num>3`. If `num> 3 or num<7` basically covers all the cases in universe so your assumption that `if(LastRun)` won't get executed when `num==1`, is false
2. Local LastRun variable will override global one and the condition `if(LastRun)` will never get executed
3. assuming you get all above things right and you are doing something additional things in if elseif section along with `LastRun=true`, `LastRun=true` will be the efficient way as you won't have to evaluate all conditions again. If you are not doing anything else apart from assigning `LastRun=true` in those if else, you can have a single `if(condition1 || condition2 || condition3){}` 

   Edit:
4. as answered by Gaurav Sharma, declare and initialize `LastRun=true`, and in `else` make it false

Comment: I didn't notice that, I already change all " >" and" <" to "=="  now

Comment: ok I understand, so It means there aren't any easier way to do that, I must use LastRun = true in every condition, else I should use if(condition1 || condition2 || condition3){} ?

Comment: Don't use it in every condition. See the other answer. declare boolean LastRun=true and in else LastRun=false. this will do

Answer (score 1):

```
#run a statement if one condition is true
import random

num = random.randint(1, 10)

condition = True

if (num > 3):
    print("Hello World")
    # do something
elif (num < 7):
    print("Hello World")
    # do something else
elif (num == 10):
    print("Hello World")
    # do something
else:
    condition = False

if(condition == True):
    print("Some statement was executed")
```

I hope this works for you!!

Comment: Is this the language which OP tagged? It looks so much like that other languages syntax....

Comment: thanks but I'm not using python in this question... but it helps me

Comment: but unfortunately I can't accept 2 answers so I give you a vote

Comment: It is not the same language, I wrote the ans in python as I was not aware how the ans would be in your language, but yeah the logic would be the same so it would help you out. Thanks for the vote